# Flutter background push notification not working for iOS

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have looked all of the other questions and answers but I couldn't solve my problem even I try everything.

I can get notification when app is on foreground for IOS and Android. But If I am on the background for IOS, I need to enter the app to see the notification.

Code For main.dart initState

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
    print("requested");
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
      assert(token != null);
      print("token");
      print(token);
    });
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        //showNotification(message);
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: Platform.isIOS ? null : myBackgroundMessageHandler,
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        // this will never called, but it's ok
        print("onLaunch: $message");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        // this will never called, but it's ok
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );

    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
    var androidInitialize = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
    var iosInitialize = IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(androidInitialize, iosInitialize);
    //flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: notificationSelected);
  }
```

I have this keys related to notifications in my info.plist.

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<string>NO</string>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>processing</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

My AppDelagete.swift file

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    if FirebaseApp.app() == nil { FirebaseApp.configure()}
    // if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    //   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    // }
    // Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    // super.application(application, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken)
 
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

      let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
      let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
      UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

I have tried with this code to send notification

```
DATA='{"notification": {"body": "Body","title": "Title Title"}, "priority": "high", "data": {"click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK", "id": "1", "status": "done", "priority":"high"}, "to": "<TOKEN>"}'
curl https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d "$DATA" -H "Authorization: key=<SERVERKEY>"
```

Thank you so much...

Comment: There's some developer discussion this is not supported currently on iOS devices. However this comment; https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/47#issuecomment-721419525 indicates support would be added in future version(s). Maybe I'm mistaken though.

Comment: I have looked here https://medium.com/@jun.chenying/flutter-tutorial-part3-push-notification-with-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-2fbdd84d3a5e. In this example there is no problem for IOS background notification. I have done same things but my code doesn't work. I have looked other questions and answer also, some of them solved. But I couldn't solve even I have done same things.

Thank you for your reply, maybe IOS background notification does not supports officially on the current version as you see. I should give up and wait for the new version:)

Comment: This issue is still open. Please check the following.
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/6290

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable "background mode" capability on your setup for the Flutter app to receive messages while in the background on iOS. Follow this [guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration#enable-background-modes-ios-only) for more details.